# Javascript - Callback vs Calling function from within another function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have the following code:

```
function download(url, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // script to download the picture here
      console.log(`Downloading ${url} ...`);

      callback();

   }, 3* 1000);
}


download(url);
```

Why do I need to have a callback function. Can't I just create another function and call that function from within the download function? I don't see the point people saying that callbacks are needed for async programming.

Comment: if you didn't have the callback then the function would immediately invoke your function when you call `download()` rather than waiting 3 seconds to call it. The callback here doesn't represent the start of the download process, but rather the _end_ of it. So once the download which takes _x_ amount of time completes, your callback would get called. Here setTimeout is being used to mimic the download process which takes _x_ amount of time. The code inside the callback would then have access to the data retrieved from performing the download, such as the downloaded content

Comment: Thank you for your response but: the console.log is called after 3 sec, why wouldn't a normal method (instead callback) be called after 3 sec then?

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks are necessary when a value depends on the response of a promise. Often when we request data from other sources, such as an external API, we don’t always know when our data will be served back.

I think what your example is alluding to would be something like this:

```
function download(url, callback) {
    console.log(`Downloading ${url} ...`);
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
          callback(null, response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
         callback(err, null)
      });
}

download("http://example.com/movies.json", function(err, response){
    // Do something with the response data
});
```

> Can't I just create another function and call that function from within the download function?

It would make more sense to pass your other function as the callback, like so:

```
function handleMovieData(err, response) {
    // Do something with the response data
}

download("http://example.com/movies.json", handleMovieData);
```

Nick Parsons' comment explains this well

---

**EDIT**: Alternatively to passing in a callback function, you could utilize async/await *(untested)*

```
async function download(url) {
    console.log(`Downloading ${url} ...`);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            resolve(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            reject(err)
        });
    })
}

const movieData = await download("http://example.com/movies.json");

handleMovieData(movieData);
```